# search users using user name and user meta in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I was saving the wordpress user as below:

```
 $user_data = array(
                    'ID' => '',
                    'user_pass' => '',
                    'user_login' => $user_name,
                    'user_email' => $trainer_email,
                    'first_name' => $first_name,
                    'last_name' => $last_name,
                    'role' => 'trainer' 
              );
$random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'course_registered',$course_registered );
wp_set_password($random_password, $user_id);
```

Presently I am using the 'WP_User_Query' method with following arguments:

```
 $args = array(
                'role' => 'trainer',
                'orderby' => 'display_name',
                'posts_per_page' => '3',
                'paged' => $paged,  
                'search'         => '*'.$trainer_name.'*',
                'search_columns' => array( 'user_login'),
                'count_total'    => true,
                'number'        => 5,
                'meta_query' => array(

                        array(
                            'key'     => 'course_registered',
                            'value'   => $course_name,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                )
            );
 $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

I want to search user if either by 'user name' or meta_key 'course_registered' else both. I tried the above& also searched many but didn't work any one. could anyone please help me..!

Answer (score 0):

Please try both way because i am not sure correct or not.

```
     $args = array(
            'role' => 'trainer',
            'orderby' => 'display_name',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
            'paged' => $paged,  
            'search'         => '*'.$trainer_name.'*',
            'search_columns' => array( 'user_login'),
            'count_total'    => true,
            'number'        => 5,
            'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'course_registered',
                        'value'   => $course_name,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
            )
        );
   $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Here just Add 'relation' => 'OR' In meta query

**OR**

use **get_users** method instead of  **WP_User_Query**

I have implement those type of searching but i am not sure in this case so please try both way one by one.

Comment: I have tried the 1st one i.e., Added 'relation' => 'OR' but it didn't work and If i try the 'get_users' method I won't use the parameter 'paged' => $paged but here I need to use that parameter for pagination. plz observe my code above once.